# How to copy specific range to another worksheet repeatedly?

Tags: vba

I am pretty new to this website, so do bear with me.

My question:

Let say I need to copy cells `A2:X16` from `Sheet 1` and paste it to `Sheet 2` 15 times then cells `A17:X31` from `Sheet 1` to `Sheet 2` 15 times, right below the one I had copied previously.

```
Sub etest()
  Dim Rng as range
  If IsNumeric(Range("BX3")) = True Then
    MsgBox "Success!"
    Set Rng = Range("A2:X16")
    Rng.Copy Rng.Offset(15).Resize(Range("BW3") * Rng.Rows.Count)
  Else
    MsgBox "please enter a valid number."
  End If
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: what you tried so far ? please share the code..

Comment: So copy `Sheet1!A2:X16` to `Sheet2!A2:X16`, `Sheet2!A17:X31`, `Sheet2!A32:X46`.... and so on 15 times.  Then copy `Sheet1!A17:X31` to `Sheet2!A212:X226`, `Sheet2!A227:X241`.... and so on 15 times?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't copy anything or set a cell value equal to another cell value (both ways are used to move the contents from one cell to another).

This code uses a couple of simple loops to copy two static ranges from `Sheet1` to dynamic ranges in `Sheet2`.

The code uses `ThisWorkbook` which is a reference to the workbook containing the code.  You could also use `ActiveWorkBook` or `Workbooks("MyNamed_WorkedBook")` depending on your needs.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim lRow As Long

    For lRow = 0 To 14
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:X16").Copy _
            Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(lRow * 15 + 2, 1)
    Next lRow

    For lRow = 15 To 29
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A17:X31").Copy _
            Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(lRow * 15 + 2, 1)
    Next lRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Darren, thank you for the reply! However in my case, I can't seem to use the ' destination:=' as there will be an error saying 'Compile error: expected expression'. So is there any other alternatives for me to use? Adding on, I need to copy range "A2:X16" from sheet 1 to the starting of sheet 2 which is from "A1" onwards, paste 15times and copy "A17:X31" from sheet 1 and paste 15 times right below the last "A2:X16" that I have copied to sheet 2 and this process continues until all the range that I have specified has been copied to sheet 2.

Comment: So basically, I am trying to copy  the entire 15 rows starting from cell "A2" up till cell "A16" in sheet 1 and copy it to sheet 2 15 times and the next 15 rows which is cell "A17" to cell "A31" in sheet 1 to sheet  2 for another 15 times.

Comment: Could you post the entire line of code that causes that error please - might be able to figure out what's gone wrong.